# Answers out of order

Tags: support, answers

I just got the Necromancer badge for an answer [so went to look at it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465855/entity-framework-add-navigation-property-manually/21455438) and noticed the answers were out of order as to what I expected them to be:
[image]

Am I wrong or should the order in this case be:

1. RPM1984
2. dav_i
3. Luponk

?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is documenting my own stupidity rather than a bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You clicked the "oldest" tab at some point (might be even days ago without noticing)

> [image]

Click "votes" tab and order will be restored.

Comment: *smashes head against keyboard*

Comment: @dav_i lol please don't, you will have to buy a new head! ;)

Comment: They come free with bodies these days though...

Comment: Wow, so you got a spare body at your disposal eh? Cool!