# Answer order why is a +69 answer below a +2 answer?

Tags: support

Checking this question [WCF Service , how to increase the timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520283/wcf-service-how-to-increase-the-timeout).

Why is the upvoted +69 answer below the +2 answer? I would highly recommend the +69 on top.

Comment: 69's on top for me, what sorting method are you using?

Comment: @NickUdell I did not set any, at least not I'm aware of any?

Comment: You've probably got it set to order by "Active" rather than "Votes". Just above the first *answer* there's a set of tabs titled "Active", "Oldest" and "Votes", clicking on one changes how the displayed answers are ordered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Answers out of order](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261976/answers-out-of-order) - I asked [exactly the same question the other day](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261976/answers-out-of-order). Maybe the UI of this needs to be looked at because it has clearly come up a few times. Or we need to look at things more carefully...

Comment: @JonK Yeah, I linked my one to emphasise that this is a commonly recurring issue.

Comment: That's what comments are for, not duplicate flags. Having a long chain of "this is a dupe of X, which is a dupe of Y, which is a dupe of Z..." helps no-one.

Comment: @JonK Is this "setting" saved when you logout etc?

Comment: Yes, it's like an account preference if you will, setting it on one question applies it to all of them, and it persists across sessions.